# CSS target html entity

Tags: css

I'm building an list in HTML with items that stands next to each other (inline). All items have to be separated with a bullet (&bull) with some padding left and right. My question: how do I target te &bull to add some padding?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Disclaimer</a>&bull;</li>
    <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a>&bull;</li>
    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>
```

The CSS code I tried is:

```
ul li a:after{
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Why not add padding directly to the `a` tag?

Comment: Something like this? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83zp03r4/1/)

Comment: If you're going to use an `:after` pseudo-element, put the symbol in the pseudo-element instead of in the markup.

Comment: @harry if I give padding left and right to the a tag, the first element will have a padding-left and be out of grid.

Comment: @BoltClock:is my answer correct as you intended ?

Comment: @user2381011: But that can be reset using the `first-child` for the `li`.

Comment: @Harry: I think i have provided a better solution than the accepted answer

Comment: Why not just put a space before and after the `&bull;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can give **margin to anchor tag**

**or** you can try this

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Disclaimer</a><span>&bull;</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a><span>&bull;</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>
```

and giv padding to span

Comment: Looks like this is the best way to do this. Thanks for the clear solution.

Comment: @user2381011:try my answer..!!

Comment: What does "you can give a margin to a tag" mean? The problem is, there is no tag around the `&bull;`.

Comment: sorry that a tag is anchor tag

Answer (score 2):

try this

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0o2ocwds/1/)

**MARKUP**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Disclaimer</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Other</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
}
ul li a:after {
    content:"\2022";
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer as well and it almost fits as a solution. Only the last element don't needs a bullet. I tried this as alternative but it doesn't work a:not(:last-child):after